# How to get space left on CD/DVD media using C code on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: c

We were using libhal APIs to know the CD/DVD type, to check on available space and if space is sufficient we used to write our data  to the media using growisofs command. With Ubuntu 10.10 it used to work. But with Ubuntu 11.10, libhal API crashes. I see that libhal is deprecated.

Could you please let me know alternative library if any? I checked on libudev but couldn't make out how to get available space on the media. Is there a way to get available space?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using the `df` command to get the space left on a particular device?

Comment: Have you tried to use "stat" on the device (/dev/scdX) ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the immediate response. I tried df and it will not list blank disk. I tried fstat and that gives only the used space. Not the total capacity.

Comment: You might be able to get the info from `wodim` if it's installed. I don't think there's a library, just the command.

Answer (score 0):

`libhal` has been superceeded by [DeviceKit](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DeviceKit).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any place where I can find sample program which uses udisks library, to know the type of media inserted in the drive and if it is writable and has enough space, write some files to it? I appreciate your help.

Comment: We were using libhal_volume_get_disc_capacity() for CD/DVD media and libhal_volume_get_size() for Blu-ray. Is there any API similar to that? Can we get this info from udisks? When I try to check on udisks API reference page, I get "Error 503 Service Unavailable".